# Configuring Essential Security Headers for Your Website

Tags: http-headers, websecurity

I'm looking for guidance on implementing key security headers for my website. Specifically, I'm interested in codes for the following headers: Content-Security-Policy, X-Frame-Options, X-Content-Type-Options, Referrer-Policy, Permissions-Policy, Strict-Transport-Security, cross-origin-embedder-policy, cross-origin-opener-policy, cross-origin-resource-policy. Could you provide me with the appropriate codes for these headers? I want to enhance the security of my website and ensure a safer online experience for visitors."

I haven't implemented any changes yet. I'm seeking guidance on how to enhance the security of my website by using the provided HTTP header codes. What steps or considerations should I be aware of before making these changes, and what outcomes can I expect in terms of improved security?